# Mission Control order criteria

Tags: mission-control

What action is determining apps & windows list order in Mission Control, left to right? It looks like this changes while using the same apps/windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Mission Control**, one of the the default settings is:

- **[√] Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use**

Unchecking it will maintain the order based on the order of a *window* placed into **Full Screen View**.